# Simple contour intergal along a circular path

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Am I correct that the the following integral evaluates to 0 since the domain of integration is a closed loop  and the integrand is continuous over the loop?
$$\int_{C(0,7)}\frac 1{(z-1)(z-3)} dz$$

Comment: Your argument seems to imply that $\int_{C(0,1)}\frac1z=0$, wouldn't it?

Comment: For what you say to be true, the integrand needs to be holomorphic in an open set containing the closed loop. This isn't true here. The integrand has poles inside the loop. Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: Hmm, no I don't. Lemme google it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a coincidence to have the correct result, but your reason is wrong, indeed the poles $1$ and $3$ are in $C(0,7)$ so by [Residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) we have
$$\int_{C(0,7)}\frac 1{(z-1)(z-3)} dz=2i\pi(Res(f,1)+Res(f,3))=2i\pi(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $C(0,\,7)$ be a circle with the center at $z=0$ and radius $r=7.$ Function $$f(z)=\frac {1}{(z-1)(z-3)}$$ has simple poles at $z_1=1,\;\;z_2=3,$ so $f(z)$ is not analytic in the  $\operatorname{int} C(0,\,7).$ However, 
$$
\int\limits_{C(0,7)}\frac 1{(z-1)(z-3)} dz=0
$$
since $\operatorname{Res}\limits_{z=\infty}{\frac {1}{(z-1)(z-3)}}=0.$